# How to disable shopping cart Icon

Tags: shopping-cart

I need to disable the shopping cart icon that is located at the top header of the webpage.
How do I disable the shopping cart icon on my website?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Magento 1.9 with RWD Theme, then locate this file:

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart/minicart.phtml
```

And delete (or comment out) this line:

```
<span class="icon"></span>
```

And that will remove the icon.

**EDIT:** Fixed path name

Comment: I am using Magento ver. 1.9.0.1

Comment: Please upvote answer if you found it useful. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, but I still see the icon.

Answer (score 0):

depends on what theme fallback you are using, copy file in your theme and remove line with this code:

**Enterprise File:**

```
app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/page/html/header.phtml
```

**Enterprise Code:**

> ```
> <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topCart') ?>
> ```

**RWD File:**

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/header.phtml
```

**RWD Code:**

> ```
> <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart_head'); ?>
> ```

Best regards